# Bootstrap, spanning two rows with an image while retaining responsiveness

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting a layout in bootstrap that is positioned using the following [image](http://imageshack.com/a/img18/8816/60nd.png).

I have two rows, the top half and the bottom half both containing two separate background gradients. The rows are both divided into 50% wide columns, with the right-most columns containing content and the left-most columns containing a single image.

My problem is that I'm unsure of how to get an element to span two rows vertically while still retaining it's fluid layout. I've positioned it absolutely but once the window scales down it doesn't stack properly. My layout is as follows.  Getting rid of the rows and splitting the page into two vertical columns results in me being unsure of how to split the background into two separate horizontal gradients. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<div class="row" style="height:50%;background-image:-webkit-gradient(etc)">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="wooo-im-an-image">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    content of a mostly blabberous nature here
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="height:50%;background-image:-webkit-gradient(etc)">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    emtpy
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    more content of a mostly blabberous nature here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you apply any `margin` or `padding ` on the div class `row`, if yes then you should not use `50%` to class `row` change it `49%` or `48%` depending on the margin or padding you gave.

Comment: neither have padding or margins. my main concern is getting the image to cross the border between the top row and the bottom row while remaining responsive.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I quite understand but I did put together an example using your picture. Pardon the CSS skills and let me know if it helps you.

```
<div class="row gradient">
    <div class="col-md-6"><div class="well inheritback">IMG<br><br><br><br><br></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><div class="well inheritback">CONTENT</div></div>

        </div>
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><div class="well inheritback">CONTENT</div></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Live Demo**

http://www.bootply.com/116896